# Django Restframework designs are not working After Hosting?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i hosted a application but the restframework design like the redcolor form alignments are not working , without design only texts are there , how to get the restframework design
need to show the restframework design and also the ststicfiles will be working properly

Answer (score 0):

It is because your project's inbuit staticfiles which is not inside your static folder (like django admin panel design, DRF browsable API design)  is not being served correctly.

Make sure you have set the `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` properly as per your requirements.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

make sure you collect the static files for that use command `python manage.py collectstatic`

What above setting dose is collect the inuilt static files as well as files in `STAIC_URL` folder and collect in `staticfiles` folder.

So, cross verify before deploying that in `staticfiles` contains all the static files which you required.

And also check that you are serving proper static file folder in deployment process. For example your you are hosting with apache then in virtual host you to add proper `\static` alias and path to your `staticfiles` folder where you collected all static files.

Comment: i do all that , this is my seetings.py . 

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# Base directory of your Django project
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Comment: After running `python manage.py collectstatic` this command, have you able to see the `rest_framework` folder inside your  project's static folder?

Comment: after adding this it worked : REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ]
}